# What does this bsr.l instruction do?

Tags: assembly, 68000, disassembly, coldfire

I'm playing with coldfire disassembler and find out this piece of code:

```
loc_F7E:
    bsr.l loc_F7E+2
    lea 12(sp),sp
    pea (284).w
    clr.l -(sp)
    move.l  a6,d0
    addi.l  #-636,d0
    move.l  d0,-(sp)

loc_F98:
    bsr.l loc_F98+2
    lea $C(sp),sp
    pea (284).w
    clr.l -(sp)
    move.l  a6,d0
    addi.l  #-$398,d0
    move.l  d0,-(sp)
```

I'm trying to figure out what is the need for those bsr.l. For me it is only jumping itself.

Comment: Is there anything else after the `move.l d0,-(sp)` in each case ?

Comment: No, just that. It is strange because it pushes some values on the stack as is if it was going to call a subroutine, but just calls itself.

Comment: Is this an executable, library, object file, or what ? I just wonder whether the bsr destination address is actually just a placeholder that gets fixed up at link/load time ?

Comment: It is an elf file and this particular code is a peace of a exported function.

Answer (score 1):

According to manual, `bsr.l *+2` has hex code `$61FF $0000 $0000`, so it is most probably result of disasming an object code with unresolved relocations, as Igor Skochinsky has mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I think these might be the result of a compiler optimization for more compact code. See "Short BRA Optimization" in the compiler guide.

Recent IDA versions disassemble such branches as `skip2` (there is also `skip1`) for HC08 and HC12 code. I haven't seen such optimization in ColdFire code before.

EDIT: or it could be just an object file with unresolved relocations.

Comment: I've disassembler this same code with REC (http://www.backerstreet.com/rec/) and it was able to tell me that those are actually function calls and show me which function. So I think you are right, but sadly IDA can't figure this out!

Comment: send a bug report then.